# Formula field using IF statement

Tags: formula, formula-field

Trying to set up a formula field that displays either YES or NO based on a picklist value field's selection. Getting a combination of errors, please advise.

I created a text formula field and have tried the below:

```
if ( or ((ISPICKVAL(Package__c,"A")),"Yes",
if ( or ((ISPICKVAL(Package__c,"B")),"Yes",
if ( or ((ISPICKVAL(Package__c,"C")),"Yes",
if ( or ((ISPICKVAL(Package__c,"D")),"Yes",
if ( or ((ISPICKVAL(Package__c,"E")),"Yes",
if ( or ((ISPICKVAL(Package__c,"F")),"Yes",
if ( or ((ISPICKVAL(Package__c,"G")),"No",
if ( or ((ISPICKVAL(Package__c,"H")),"No",
if ( or ((ISPICKVAL(Package__c,"I")),"No"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for the `CASE()` function. Chaining a bunch of `IF()`s together would work, but that would be painful. You could reduce typing by grouping the tests for various picklist values together, but `CASE()` is going to be much less painful to write (and read).

Before I get to that though, let's examine why your current formula is running into errors.

### First, you're not using the `IF()` function correctly

If you look at [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.customize_functions_parent.htm&type=5) (a very good thing to reference while building formulas), you'll see that `IF()` looks like this

```
IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

Changing things around just a bit so that we end up conforming to best practice (each statement on its own line, indent one extra level when you encounter an open parenthesis)

```
IF(
    logical test,
    value_if_true,
    value_if_false
)
```

It takes 3 parameters, all of which are required, and they need to be in that order (separated by a comma).
If we try to format your formula in that manner, it'll look like

```
IF(
    OR(
        (ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "A")),
        "Yes",
        IF(
            OR(
                (ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "B")),
                "Yes",
/* I'm not typing out the rest */
```

You never end up having a closing parenthesis for any of your `IF()`, and everything is smashed into the `logical_test`. Here, you want

- your "logical test" to be "has the user selected value "A" in this picklist
- your "value if true" to be "yes"
- and your "value if false" to be a nested `IF()` which returns either "Yes" or "No"

Being mindful of parenthesis and keeping the above in mind, you can shuffle things around a bit to get closer to a proper formula

```
IF(
    /* This OR() is our logical test */
    /* The open paren needs a matching close paren*/
    OR(
        /* No need for the extra parens surrounding ISPICKVAL() */
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "A")
    ),
    "Yes",
    /* We can nest IF() functions inside of an IF() function */
    /* This gives us an if-else if, which can be a useful construction */
    IF(
        OR(
            ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "B")
        ),
        "Yes",

/* I'm still not typing out the rest */
```

### Second, you're not using the `OR()` function correctly

`OR()` takes one or more boolean values, and returns `true` if *any* of them are true. Working out the proper usage of `IF()` kinda sorted this issue for us as well, but `OR(ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "B"), "Yes", IF(...))` is not correct because `"Yes"` is not a boolean value, and the nested `IF()` doesn't return a boolean value either.

You *can* use an `OR()` with only one value, but that doesn't make too much sense. In this case, the `OR()`s can be completely removed. In general, the less typing we do, the less likely it is for us to make mistakes.

```
IF(
    /* ISPICKVAL() returns true/false, so it is suitable for our */
    /*   logical test all on its own */
    ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "A"),
    "Yes",
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "B"),
        "Yes",
/* I'm still not typing out the rest */
)
```

We're getting closer. This would work, but it could still be improved further.

### Third, your composition of `IF()` and `OR()` is incorrect

I get the feeling that you were trying to turn natural language into a formula. Something like

> If package is A, then yes, or if package is B, then yes, or if package is C...

Writing out, in plain language, what you intend your formula to do is definitely a helpful tool for planning/organizing a formula. You do need to kinda stick close to how formulas work though, and that's where I think your attempt fell apart. It's something that takes a bit of practice, but isn't too hard once you gain some familiarity with formulas.

I would write this in plain language like so

> If package is A, then yes, else if package is B, then yes, else if package is C...

That would lead you to the nested `IF()` approach, but it seems like we're repeating ourselves quite a bit. While we can only compare a field to a single value at a time, we can reintroduce the `OR()` and group all of the comparisons that should result in "yes" into a single logical test

> If package is A or package is B or package is C, then yes, else...

Turning that into a formula

```
IF(
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "A"),
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "B"),
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "C"),
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "D"),
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "E"),
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "F")
    ),
    "Yes",
    IF(
        OR(
            ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "G"),
            ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "H"),
            ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "I")
        ),
        "No",
        "Invalid value"
    )
)
```

That's much more compact (if we ignore the extra spacing that we're using for formatting purposes), and much less repetition.

**If you wanted to use `IF()`, this is how you would want to do it**

### One point I've glossed over a bit

Is that formulas require parenthesis to be *balanced*. For every open parenthesis, there must be a matching closing parenthesis.
There can end up being a lot of parenthesis, which is really hard for our brains to track. By formatting your formula according to best practice, it makes it really easy to see when (and where) you've made a mistake.
compare

```
IF(field__c = 1, "A", IF(field__c = 2, "B", IF(field__c = 3, "C", IF(field__c = 4, "D", IF(field__c = 5, "E", "F")))
```

to

```
IF(
    field__c = 1, 
    "A", 
    IF(
        field__c = 2, 
        "B", 
        IF(
            field__c = 3, 
            "C", 
            IF(
                field__c = 4, 
                "D", 
                IF(
                    field__c = 5, 
                    "E",
                    "F"
                )
            )
        )
```

The second one is much easier to see that you've missed some closing parenthesis (specifically, 2 are missing).

### But we can still do better with `CASE()`

`CASE()` is one of the few functions that can work directly on picklists, so you don't need `ISPICKVAL()` with it. It also means that you don't have to repeat writing `Package__c` multiple times.

Its usage, with formatting, is like so

```
CASE(
    field,
    value 1, result 1,
    value 2, result 2,
    ...
    value n, result n,
    default result (if none of the values matched)
)
```

The minimum number of parameters is 4 (field, one value and result, the default). In your case

```
CASE(
    Package__c,
    "A", "Yes",
    "B", "Yes",
    "C", "Yes",
    "D", "Yes",
    "E", "Yes",
    "F", "Yes",
    "G", "No",
    "H", "No",
    "I", "No",
    "Invalid value"
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the in-depth reply and explanation. Really appreciated. I am very new to using formulas in Salesforce so this has already helped tremendously.

Comment: One helluva response, nice work DerekF

Answer (score 2):

If functions are written in the form of:

```
If(condition, value_when_true, value_when_false)
```

And the or function is in the form of:

```
or(condition1, condition2, ..., conditionN)
```

However, you can skip all this and simply write:

```
CASE(
Package__c,
"A", "Yes",
"B", "Yes",
"C", "Yes",
"D", "Yes",
"E", "Yes",
"F", "Yes",
"G", "No",
"H", "No",
"I", "No",
NULL
)
```

Where case is in the form of:

```
case(field, value1, output1, ..., valueN, outputN, default_value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple using OR condition as below

```
IF(
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "A"),
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "B"),
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "C"),
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "D"),
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "E"),
        ISPICKVAL(Package__c, "F")
    ),
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```